# use memcache for fragment cache

Tags: php, caching, memcached

How to use memcache for fragment cache?
I use zend framework libraries.
See this exapmle.

```
require_once 'Zend/Cache.php';
$frontendOptions = array(
    'lifetime' => 300,
    'automatic_serialization' => false
);
$backendOptions = array('cache_dir' => './zendCache/');

$cache = Zend_Cache::factory('Output', 'File', $frontendOptions, $backendOptions);

if (!$cache->start('rightColumn')) {
    // html and everything will cached in file.

    $cache->end();
}
```

Now I want to use memcache for fragment cache.

```
require_once 'Zend/Cache.php';
$frontend = array('caching' => true, 'lifetime' => 1800, 'automatic_serialization' => true);

$backendOptions = array('cache_dir' => './zendCache/');
$backend = array(
    'servers' => array(
        array('host' => '127.0.0.1', 'port' => 11211)
    ),
    'compression' => false
);
$cache = Zend_Cache::factory('Core', 'Memcached', $frontend, $backend);
$key = 'cacheKey';
if (($result = $cache->load($key)) === false) {
    $cache->save($result, $key);
}
echo $result;
```

How solve this ?

Comment: Can you narrow down your question? It's not clear what exactly your problem is here.

Comment: i want use memcache for fragment cache. for example cache <body></body> via memcache